# Customising org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, classloader, websphere-8

**Background**

We have an on-line application using JSF2.0 (One that comes with Web-sphere application server v8.5.5) + PrimeFaces 5.0

**Requirement**

For a particular requirement, we have to customise org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer. We noticed that there is no clean way to customise org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer . 
As a work around we created a class  org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer in Web Source folder. This class ends up in WebInf/classes

**Issue**

Upon initial deployment prime-faces.jar  loaded the version of org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer in WebInf/classes and every thing worked as expected.
Upon further investigation it became apparent that the war class loading behaviour is inconsistent. We couldn't guarantee which version of org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer is loaded by the Prime Faces frame work. At times the application loads the version of org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer from WebInf/classes other times it loads the version from WebInf/lib/primefaces-5.0.jar

The Servlet3.0 clearly states

*The Web application class loader must load classes from the WEB-INF/classes
Directory first, and then from library JARs in the WEB-INF/lib directory.*

So not sure why we are experiencing this inconsistent behaviour.

**What was tried & suggested**

- We tried referencing the
  org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer in servlet startup
  listener.
- One of my colleagues suggested to remove    org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer in primefaces jar 
  file. This would resolve the issue, but customising third party library is against our company policy.

**Summary**

In conclusion what we are really looking is for a way to customise org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer in prime-faces without patching the primefaces jar file.

Comment: Create your own component that extends the PF one? But I'd personally fix the weird WebSphere behaviour. (maybe by patching the JSF version (JSF 2.0 is not a real implementation/version, it is an spec one)

Comment: Off-topic: it is PrimeFaces, not Prime Faces, prime-faces or primefaces ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje . yes it looks like a web-sphere class loading problem (not as per servlet spec) . Raising a PMR will take long to address. So I was keen on a work around, where I can manage this situation.

Comment: Then 'create your own component that extends...' is the way to go I think

Comment: I will give it a go. Thank you

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for the effort. Just figured out a work around for the issue.

Comment: Ahhhhhh... yes that was what I was looking for to... Did not search to good obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an solution for this issue

Adding the following snippet of code in applications faces-config.xml allows me to override the MessageRenderer in primefaces

```
   <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.MessageRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>my.CustomRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
```